# Store a value result of an event for another event C#

Tags: c#, variables, events, button

I have a little dilemma.
I have 2 events activated by 2 buttons. 
I the first event generate some values that i need to use in the second event.
But i can not find a way to pass the value or set up a global variable.

```
namespace SPACE2

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string myvalue2 = operation(myvalue1); 
    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myvalue1;
        .....code...
        myvalue1 = result;


    }


    namespace SPACE1
    {

    this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
    this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);

    }
```

Comment: that doesn't compile.

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the code so that compiles. Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare `myvalue1` as a field of the class (yes, a Form is a class) instead of inside the click event.

```
private string myvalue1;
```

You will then need to do some validation, since the user (I assume) could click the buttons in a different order than you expect.